# Account Linking response for Actions On Google not correct in Hindi

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I am making custom Google Action and in my app I am using account linking. The response for when Google asks the user for confirmation in English is Correct but the same in Hindi is not.

English Account Linking question by Google:

```
To get your account details, I need to link your my test app account to Google. Is that okay?
```

Hindi Account Linking question by Google :

```
अपने खाते का विवरण प्राप्त करने के लिए, मुझे आपके टेस्ट ऐप्लिकेशन खाते को Google से जोड़ना होगा। आपको इससे कोई समस्या तो नहीं है?`
```

So in English response, I will reply back 'Yes' or 'Okay' if I don't have any problem in linking my account. But in Hindi, the response for the question asked ideally would be 'नहीं', for which Google takes it as a  no and cancels the account linking process. I cannot modify the response as this is the default response from Google.

Can someone please help me with what to do with this problem.

Comment: I think you should report this problem directly with google so that they can fix that translation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please file an issue with the Actions on Google support team: https://developers.google.com/assistant/support

Answer (score 0):

Please report the problem directly to the Google Developer team. hope they will help you since it isn't a technical problem so they are the one who can help you.